How do I fix the Java unsatisfied link error when using JNA in Apache MiNiFi running inside a podman container
I have an Apache NiFi dataflow that transports data between two directories on my system through POSIX message queues using two NiFi processors that I made. These processors use JNA to make the calls to the C libraries to actually interact with the message queues. When trying to run this NiFi dataflow in a podman container with MiNiFi, it does not work and my two processors are returning an error:
ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] c.o.n.processors.ListenPOSIX.ListenPOSIX ListenPOSIX[id=cfa08554-8e00-35d8-87f2-6fc21bfa446c] Processing halted: yielding [1 sec]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'mq_open': java: undefined symbol: mq_open
    at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:252)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:600)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:576)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:562)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:243)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.mq_open(Unknown Source)
    at com.owlcyberdefense.nifi.processors.ListenPOSIX.ListenPOSIX.onTrigger(ListenPOSIX.java:139)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1361)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:247)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:102)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Java can't seem to find the libraries which have the mq commands. The rest of the dataflow works as expected.
I'm not sure which part of the puzzle isn't fitting in. I don't believe it's JNA itself acting up as the dataflow works on my host, my running theory is that it is looking in the wrong place in my container for these C libraries, and I don't know how to change that: the various solutions I've found online seem to change nothing. I have no clue if this is actually the cause of the error though.
Running ldd --version in the container yields:
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
I have tried some solutions online such as in the Dockerfile adding: ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64
This is supposed to tell Java where to look to find the methods like mq_open used by the NiFi processors. This did not have any effect it would seem.
I double checked my data flow on host and ensured it worked. No parts of the data flow or processors were modified between me double checking it worked on my host and moving them into MiNiFi in the podman container.
Another thing worth noting in the Dockerfile is the following line: RUN yum install -y podman runc cmake3 make gcc gcc-c++ --skip-broken
The --skip-broken line is there as without it the container fails to build. I originally suspected that this may be the source of the issue, maybe causing the C libraries to not install and therefore them not being accessible by Java, but glibc is installed in the container. I am not sure, however.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please show is your library in which you've mapped this function, we can't help unless we know how you're trying to load this library.  See the JNA NativeLibrary class javadocs for pointers on where it looks and how to debug the loading process.

So I was successful in fixing this. My container has glibc version 2.17, whereas my host has version 2.34: in the libc.so.6 library, the mq_xxxx methods are listed there in 2.34 but not in 2.17. My attempts to update this from 2.17 to 2.34 failed for other reasons, but I don't see why this wouldn't work. How I did it instead was I installed the glibc-devel library, then in my interface class I changed the library I am loading from "c" to "rt"
Here is what it looks like:
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;

public interface LibC extends Library {
    LibC INSTANCE = Native.load("rt", LibC.class);

    int mq_open(String name, int oflag, int mode, Pointer attr);
    int mq_close(int mqd);
    int mq_send(int mqd, byte[] msg, int len, int priority);
    int mq_receive(int mqd, byte[] msg, int len, IntByReference priority);
    int mq_unlink(String name);
    Pointer strerror(int errno); 
    int mq_getattr(int mqd, Pointer attr);
}

Where line 7 used to be:
LibC INSTANCE = Native.load("c", LibC.class);

